# SVG overlay on top of UIImagePickerController with UIImagePickerController responding to gestures (iPhone/iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I need to place a vector, ideally SVG overlay over UIImagePickerController. I need the underlying `UIImagePickerController` to respond to gestures while the overlay should only be an inactive image.

I tried the cameraOverlayView of the UIImagePickerController to show UIWebView with loaded SVG and with transparent background. It does show the overlay as expected, but it responds to gestures and the underlying `UIImagePickerController` does not. I need it the other way around.

1. Can this be achieved with UIWebView as an overlay at all? If yes, how?
2. If `UIWebView` is not the right solution, how can I draw vectors from a file (SVG, EPS...) as an overlay and achieve the desired behavior?
3. The cameraOverlayView draws the overlay over the camera even when the shutter is closed (the shutter leaves are displayed in the UI) - I only need overlay when the camera is running - showing live image. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I am using UIWebView to overlay an SVG image onto some standard iOS UI.  In my
case I am using the SVG to provide a 'tour' of the underlying UI.  I am still 
working on this, so I have some unanswered questions.

1. SVG animations do not appear to
   work, although I may turn out to be
   wrong in this.
2. I have only using simple SVG with no
   links to a .CSS style sheet or other
   documents.
3. I am using a class derived from
   UIWebView, and have it cover the
   entire surface.    You could
   probably have a smaller UIWebView,
   but I have not tried this.
4. Here is a simple example of the SVG

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
> <svg version="1.1"
>   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
>   id="tutorialLayout" width="480px" height="320px">
>   <desc>UI Feature</desc>
>   <defs>
>     <rect id="cover" width="480px" height="320px" opacity="0.3" fill="black"/>
>   </defs>
>   <g>
>     <rect id="top"    x="000px" y="000px" width="480px" height="290px" opacity="0.3" fill="black"/>
>     <rect id="bottom" x="000px" y="310px" width="480px" height="010px" opacity="0.3" fill="black"/>
>     <rect id="left"   x="000px" y="290px" width="010px" height="020px" opacity="0.3" fill="black"/>
>     <rect id="right"  x="200px" y="290px" width="280px" height="020px" opacity="0.3" fill="black"/>   
>     <text x="10" y="280" alignment-baseline="bottom"
>       style="font-size:32; font-family:Arial fill:black;"
>       >The totals are reported here</text>
>   </g>
> </svg>
> ```

5) Here is a fragment of the code to load the SVG

```
NSBundle *bundle  = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *svg     = @"svg";
[svgView_ addRequest: [NSURL URLWithString: [bundle pathForResource: @"Arrow"    ofType: svg ]] seconds:  5];
[svgView_ addRequest: [NSURL URLWithString: [bundle pathForResource: @"t_help"   ofType: svg ]] seconds: 15];
[svgView_ addRequest: [NSURL URLWithString: [bundle pathForResource: @"t_layout" ofType: svg ]] seconds:  5];
```

The implementing class

```
@implementation RAWebView
//! Internal - process next request
- (void)        nextRequest {
    RAWebRequest  *next = [[urlStack_ pop] retain];
    if ( next == nil ) {
        [self setHidden: TRUE];
    } else {
        [super loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [next url]]];
        [super setHidden: FALSE];
        [super setUserInteractionEnabled: TRUE];
        if ( 0 < [next periodSecs] ) {
            int64_t delta = 1000000000;
            delta *= [next periodSecs];
            dispatch_after( dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delta),
                           dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                           ^{ [self nextRequest]; } );
        }
        [next release];
    }    
}
//! Add RAWebRequest to queue
- (void)        addRequest: (RAWebRequest*) web_request {
    if ( urlStack_ == nil ) {
        urlStack_ = [[D4iStack alloc] init];
        [self setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
        [self setOpaque: NO];        
    }
    if ( 0 == [urlStack_ count] ) {
        dispatch_after( dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10000 ),
                         dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                         ^{ [self nextRequest]; } );
    }
    [urlStack_ push: web_request];
}
//! Add RAWebRequest to queue 
- (void)        addRequest: (NSURL*) display_url seconds: (NSUInteger) period_secs {
    RAWebRequest *request = [[RAWebRequest alloc] initWithUrl: display_url seconds: period_secs];
    [self addRequest: request];
    [request release];
}
//! On user touch, hide self and empty urlStack
- (UIView*)     hitTest: (CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [urlStack_ clear];
    [self setHidden: TRUE];
    return nil;
}
//! NSObject dealloc
- (void)        dealloc {
    [urlStack_ clear];
    [urlStack_ release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end

@implementation RAWebRequest
@synthesize url = url_, periodSecs = periodSecs_;

//! Init with set values
- (id)          initWithUrl: (NSURL*) display_url seconds: (NSUInteger) period_secs {
    if (( self = [super init] )) {
        url_        = [display_url retain];
        periodSecs_ = period_secs;        
    }
    return self;
}
//! NSObject dealloc 
- (void)        dealloc {
    [url_   release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the great example Chris!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out the open source SVGView project for rendering SVG files with iOS:
https://github.com/mattrajca/SVGKit

I happen to be using this fork, which has improved parser support, among other things:
https://github.com/reklis/SVGKit

In many cases, it should be as simple to display an SVG as:

```
SVGView *svgView = [[SVGView alloc] initWithDocument:
                                    [SVGDocument documentNamed:@"overlay.svg"]];
[self.view addSubview:svgView];
```